# Portable webserver for static site in Ubuntu

Tags: webserver, development-environment

I'm working on some pre-compiled website and I have a web-development project with only a static files in it (HTML, CSS, JS, images, fonts, etc).

In order to test it on development machine I need a web-server capable of serving static files over HTTP. I don't want to use some heavy artillery like Vagrant and nginx/apache. I'm looking for a web-server that can be invoked from the command line with a simple command and/or that have a configuration file stored in the project, not in the system.

What are my options in the field of portable web-servers? I need it to run on Ubuntu.

I've heard about Python's `SimpleHTTPServer` and PHP's [built-in webserver](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php). Are there any other alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

I would not dismiss Nginx. Nginx is quite lightweight and very good at serving static data.

Comment: Thanks Roman! I agree, `nginx` rocks with static content and FCGI (I'm using it in production myself), but  it's not portable.